# Toggle geojson layer interactivity

Tags: leaflet

First of all, since it's my first question, I'm sorry if I make any mistakes.

I'd like to "deactivate" a Geojson Layer, composed by a feature collection with many polygons (or lines). I have seen how to create it with the option interactive = yes or interactive = no, but I can't find out how to toggle this dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: last thing I tried was this:

```
var onEachFeature = function(feature, layer) {
    function onmouseover(e) {
        var layer = e.target;
        var activeLayer = ___get_active_layergroup();
        if (activeLayer === null){
            layer.setStyle({
                cursor: 'move'
            });
        } else if (activeLayer.hasLayer(layer)){
            layer.setStyle({
                cursor: 'pointer'
            });
        } else {
            layer.setStyle({
                cursor: 'move'
            });
        }
    }
    function onmouseout(e) {

    }

    return {
        mouseover: onmouseover,
        mouseout: onmouseout
    }
}
```

And I put that function in the layer initialization.

`___get_active_layergroup` is accesible in the context.

EDIT2: 
It works if instead of `setStyle` I use this:

```
var element = layer.getElement();
if (element.classList.contains("leaflet-interactive")) { 
    element.classList.remove("leaflet-interactive") 
}
```

But I don't really like how it works. I can see the pointer while I'm moving the mouse blinking (because it takes a few milliseconds process the mouseover I think).

Comment: a bit of code would help to start the responses. Have you tried something already?

Comment: Hi @Patrik_P, I put the last thing I tried in the description

Comment: I have found a solution, but it doesn't look completely fine.